# What is a good book or site to start learning development on the Palm Treo/Centro?

Tags: palm-os

I'm an experienced programmer looking for a good reference and tutorial for developing for Palm OS in either C or C++?  What are some good (up to date) books, reference manuals, and sites that would set me in a direction to start developing on the Palm Treo and Centro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no up to date books on PalmOS, because the OS hasn't changed in years.  But [Palm OS Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565928563) was good for its time. Maybe you want to develop for the new Pre, then you might want [Palm webOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155255) instead.

Comment: I haven't coded on the Palm in anger in a long time, but this is still the latest book that I'm aware of.  I won't link it, but <shudder> Wikipedia has a fairly comprehensive write-up of the history of the PalmOS.  Also, their developer support used to be pretty good.  It may require you to sign up and sign an NDA (it did in mid-2001) but I seriously doubt that that's still a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is the PalmOS programming http://johwil.aquariusoft.org/dev/PalmDev/tut/IDGBooks-PalmOSProgrammingBible.pdf

At that point it's probably a good idea just to read the API docs along with sourcecode from sourceforge or www.palmopensourec.com